# Given an eigen values evaluate $S*\tiny\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Eigen value is given as $\lambda = 2,-3,5$..

$v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-3\\-2  \end{bmatrix}$ $v_{2} =\begin{bmatrix} -2\\7\\5 \end{bmatrix}$ $v_{2} =\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

A) WRITE DOWN THE VALUES OF Sv1, Sv2 and Sv3
by definition this is the eigen values times the corresponding eigen vector (where eigen value 2 corresponds to --> $V_{1}$)

B) Let $w=7v_{1}+3v_{2}+3v_{3}$ calculate w and SW
I basically used basic constant time vector and vector addition...

$$w = 7\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-3\\-2  \end{bmatrix} + 3\begin{bmatrix} -2\\7\\5 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 2\\-6\\4 \end{bmatrix}  $$

By the definition of an eigenvalue multiplying the product of S and its Eigen with a constant multiple then the answer is in proportion to the normal eigen value and factor.

$$Sw = 2*7\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-3\\-2  \end{bmatrix} + -3*3\begin{bmatrix} -2\\7\\5 \end{bmatrix}+5\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 32\\-105\\-78 \end{bmatrix}  $$ Is this right?

c) This is where i get lost. It says "By referring to b or otherwise evaluate $S*\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0  \end{bmatrix}$"

How do i apply the eigen vectors heere?

D) hence find the matrix S...
What!!! How even?

Comment: There's a slight mistake in your calculation for b)
You drop the $3$ from before the vector $v_3$ in your calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Write $(0,1,0)$ in terms of the eigenvectors, say $(0,1,0)=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3.$ Then

$$S(0,1,0)=a_1S(v_1)+a_2S(v_2)+a_3S(v_3)$$ where you know all terms in RHS.

In a similar way you can get $S(1,0,0)$ and $S(0,0,1).$ Finally, isn't $S(1,0,0)$ the first column of $S?$

Comment: Hey how did i go for a and b? 

How did the eigenvectors come into play? Are a1 to a3 the eigen values given... Or are the (0,1,0}?

Comment: Solving the linear system $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3=(0,1,0)$. You should get $a_1=2,a_2=1,a_3=-1.$

Comment: Was A and B fine? How does this connect to the result of b?

Comment: Your answer to A and B are correct. Just a typo. Line $10$ should read $Sw=\cdots$ What do you mean by "the result of b"?

Comment: I was given a hint that said "By referring to b or otherwise evaluate $S*\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0  \end{bmatrix}$"

Comment: It what I have said before. Write $(0,1,0)=2v_1+v_2-v_3$ and do the same as in b.

Comment: Oh ok just to clarify.. so you have a1 and a2 and a3 by row reducing a 3x3 vector made up of v1, v2 and v3?

Comment: Thank you absolutely spot on! I finally got it.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand you have a matrix $S$ that has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=2$, $\lambda_2=-3$ and $\lambda_3=5$, with corresponding eigevectors:

$v_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-3\\-2  \end{bmatrix}$ $v_{2} =\begin{bmatrix} -2\\7\\5 \end{bmatrix}$ $v_{2} =\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

So, your matrix diagonalizable and it is:
$
S= PDP^{-1}
$
with:
$$
P= \begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&0\\
-3&7&0\\
-2&5&1
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and

$$
D= \begin{bmatrix}
2&0&0\\
0&-3&0\\
0&0&5
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
So you have the answer to D) and you can find the answer to C) eavluating the product.

Comment: Do you think the OP is familiar with this result?

Comment: I don't think we've covered that topic yet